# HOW to copy many rows in the same time?

Tags: excel

i have huge data.

HOW to copy many rows in the same time?

where the rows, that i want, are repeated in systematic approach for each four rows. please, see the figure.

thank you in advance for any help.
[MANY ROWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5mnC.jpg)

Comment: [Why not images of Code and Sample Data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in F2 and copy over and down:

```
=INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*4+2)
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks, it does work like magic

Comment: @amer please choose one to mark as correct, by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer that you choose.  It is something only you can do.   It will close out the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like,

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
   .range("a2:b2, a6:b6, a10:b10, a14:b14, a18:b18").copy _
      destination:=.range("f2")
end with
```

Alternately, with 'thousands of rows' you could create a union with a loop.

```
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set rng = .Range("a2:b2")
    For rw = 6 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 4
        Set rng = Union(rng, .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 2))
    Next rw
   rng.Copy Destination:=.Range("f2")
End With
```